# How to Connect IPFS client in xamarin forms.?

Tags: ipfs, c#

i need to start ipfs client in My xamarin forms app.Now with the emulator it is working but when it comes to device i don't know how to connect.?I want to connection for both platform(ios and android).

My Code to start IPFS client on Genymotion

```
CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken(false);
IpfsClient ipfs = new IpfsClient("http://10.0.3.2:5001");

var options = new AddFileOptions { OnlyHash = true };
var fsn = await ipfs.FileSystem.AddFileAsync(fileData.FilePath, options);
Console.WriteLine((string)fsn.Id);
```